# Azure Application Insights error when deploying to tomcat

Tags: azure, tomcat, gradle, build.gradle, azure-application-insights

I kept running into the following error messages when after deploying my application using Application Insights. I'm following the Microsoft tutorial, found here, but there still seems to be a dependency error.

- `Error creating bean with name 'webRequestTrackingFilterRegistrationBean'`
- `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.microsoft.applicationinsights.internal.config.ReflectionUtils.addClass(Ljava/lang/Class;)`

Comment: It seems you are using SpringBoot. I would recommend using ApplicationInsights-Spring-boot-starter and follow this (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/azure/spring-framework/configure-spring-boot-java-applicationinsights?view=azure-java-stable) tutorial

Answer (score 0):

I found that the issue was with my dependencies. It turns out that I needed to add the insight-core dependency. Previously I only had applicationinsights-web as my dependency and this ran fine locally but did did not work once I deployed my app.

```
implementation group: 'com.microsoft.azure', name:    'applicationinsights-core', version: '2.+'
```